# Pass gridview items to textbox and dropdown list inside of Jquery UI?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is there a way to pass value of selected row in gridview to a textbox and dropdownlist inside a jQueryUI dialog? I was able to pass the value in labels but I want it to be in textbox and dropdownlist. This is my code to pass the value to labels:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
$(document).on("click", "[id*=LinkButton1]", function () {
    $("[id*=lblNameView]").html($(".name", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
    $("[id*=lblLocationView]").html($(".Locationd", $(this).closest("tr")).html());
    var dlg = jQuery("#dialogViewing").dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "View Audit Findings",
        resizable: true,
        width: 480,
        height: 290,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 200
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 200
        },
    });
    return false;
   dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
});
```

```html
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" ItemStyle-CssClass="name" HeaderText="Tenant Name" SortExpression="TenantCode" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Locationd" ItemStyle-CssClass="Locationd" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Locationd" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Update:

```
    <div id="dialogViewing" style="display:none;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="lblName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Location 1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Location 2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Location 3</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
         </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
dlg.find("input[id*=lblName]").val($(".name", $(this).closest("tr")).html())
dlg.find("select[id*=ddlLocation]").val($(".Locationd", $(this).closest("tr")).html())
```

Comment: Can you post #dialogViewing html? Basically find will search for your textbox and dropdownlist and replace their values. Can you post errors from browser console too?

Comment: It worked on the textbox but in dropdown it doesn't.